# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py

я понимаю что ета ошибка означает что у меня чет с отступами но я немогу понять что иммено
вот код та проблемная часть:

```
@client.command()
async def turn(cxt, url : str):
    song_there = os.path.isfile('song.mp3')

    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove('song.mp3')
            print('[log] Старый файл удален')
       except PermissionError:
       print('[log] Не удалось удалить файл')

    await ctx.send('Пожалуйста ожидайте')

    voice = get (client.voice_clients, guild = ctx.guild)

    ydl_opts = {
        'format' : "bestaudio/best",
        'postprocessors' : [{
            'key' : 'FFmpegExtartAudio',
            'preferredcodec' : 'mp3' ,
            'preferredquality' : '192'
        }]

    }
    
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDl(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        print('[log] Загружаю музыку...')
        ydl.download([url])

    for file in os.listdir('./')
        if file.endswith('.mp3'):
            name = file
            print(f'[log] переименовываю файл: {file}')
            os.rename(file, 'song.mp3')

    voice.play(discord.FFmpegExctartAudio('song.mp3'), after = lambda e: print(f'[log] {name}, музыка закончила свое звучанние'))
    voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
    voice.source.volume = 0.07

    song_name = name.rsplit('-', 2)
    await ctx.send(f'Сейчас проигрывает музыка: {song_name[0]}')
```

Comment: Невооружённым глазом виден полный бардак в отступах.

Answer (score 2):

```
try:
    if song_there:
        os.remove('song.mp3')
        print('[log] Старый файл удален')
    except PermissionError:
    print('[log] Не удалось удалить файл')
```

В этом участке кода отсутствует отступ перед "print('[log] ...".

Правильный вариант:

```
try:
    if song_there:
        os.remove('song.mp3')
        print('[log] Старый файл удален')
except PermissionError:
    print('[log] Не удалось удалить файл')
```

Comment: По крайней мере первая ошибка что я увидел :p

Comment: спасибо большое